# How to get an Excel Blank Cell Value in Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I have a huge excel file with tons of columns which looks like this :-

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
abc             def             ghi
        mno             pqr
......
```

This is the code that I wrote to print these values:

```
try {
    FileInputStream inputStr = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    XSSFWorkbook xssfWork = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStr) ;
    XSSFSheet sheet1 = xssfWork.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator rowItr = sheet1.rowIterator();

    while ( rowItr.hasNext() ) {
        XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rowItr.next();
        System.out.println("ROW:-->");
        Iterator cellItr = row.cellIterator();

        while ( cellItr.hasNext() ) {
            XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cellItr.next();
            System.out.println("CELL:-->"+cell.toString());
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output generated by this code is :-

```
ROW:-->
CELL:-->Column1
CELL:-->Column2
CELL:-->Column3
CELL:-->Column4
CELL:-->Column5
ROW:-->
CELL:-->abc
CELL:-->def
CELL:-->ghi
ROW:-->
CELL:-->mno
CELL:-->pqr
```

So, If we look at the output above we can note that the cells where I left blank values was not picked up by the POI library , is there a way in which I can get these values as null. or a way to recognize that the values presented skipped blank cells?

Thanks.

Answer (score 76):

If you want to get all cells, no matter if they exist or not, then the iterator isn't for you. Instead, you need to manually fetch the appropriate cells, likely with a missing cell policy

```
for(Row row : sheet) {
   for(int cn=0; cn<row.getLastCellNum(); cn++) {
       // If the cell is missing from the file, generate a blank one
       // (Works by specifying a MissingCellPolicy)
       Cell cell = row.getCell(cn, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
       // Print the cell for debugging
       System.out.println("CELL: " + cn + " --> " + cell.toString());
   }
}
```

There's more details on all of this in [the Apache POI documentation on iterating over cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)

Comment: `row.getCell()` method is deprecated.

Comment: It's `row.getCell(short)` that's deprecated. Sorry.

Comment: It really does! POI has loads of unit tests showing it works just fine!

Comment: In POI 3.9, the correct syntax appears to be row.getCell(cn, Row. CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).

Comment: @paul_sns That's always been the syntax, was a typo on my part, doh! It's a MissingCellPolicy, but the static instances live on Row

Comment: Update: `Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK` should be `MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK`

Comment: I had been facing exactly same issue, this solution worked for me

Comment: Easiest solution you can get, this solution worked like a charm for me

Answer (score 14):

I have been frustrated by this same problem.  Here is what I found with poi-3.7-20101029 and poi-3.8.

RowIterator and CellIterator do not support iterating over NULL cells or rows -- only physically defined cells (which can be BLANK).

The solution that returns what I expect requires using the 0-based `Row.getCell([int], Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK)`, much like Chavira's answer alludes to (assuming 8 cell rows). Or you can use the `Cell.columnIndex` value while iterating to check for jumping numbers...

Annoyingly, after creating blank cells using method #1, the iterators will return the now created BLANK cells. I consider it a bug that MissingCellPolicy is ignored by CellIterator.

Comment: Ran into the same problem and using the 0 based index approach (not via the foreach) and the CREAT_NULL_AS_BLANK MissingRowPolicy worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is quite simple: Excel files can contain as many rows and as many columns as possibles, so returning all available blank rows and columns will render the cells huge and memory intensive.

Assuming you have a 10x10 sheet, in Excel, it's not "exactly" 10x10 since you can add 11x10 very easily with blank cell, so should POI return the 11th column?

One way to do what you're requesting is to use `HSSFCell.getColumnIndex()`.

Example:

```
//Assuming your have a 2 dimensional array.
String[][] values = ......;// It is assigned

POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(fileName));
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileSystem);

//Going through every worksheet.
for (int sheetPos = 0; sheetPos < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); sheetPos++) {
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetPos);

    int rowPos = 0;
    Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();
    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();

        Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();
        while (cells.hasNext()) {
            HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
            String value = "";

            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    value = BigDecimal.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue()).toPlainString();
                    break;

                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    value = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    break;

                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                    value = "";
                    break;

                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                    value = cell.getCellFormula();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            values[rowPos][cell.getColumnIndex()] = value;
        }

        rowPos++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Row.getCell(int) **is not deprecated**! No idea why you think that, but I can assure you that it isn't - see the [JavaDocs](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell(int)) for proof.

Comment: @Gagravarr, sorry, it's the `Row.getCell(short)` that's deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Below is what worked for me.  The "row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK" did not appear to be valid but that could be lack of NPOI knowledge.

```
HSSFCell dataCell= (HSSFCell)row.GetCell(column, NPOI.SS.UserModel.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
```

Comment: NPOI? If you are using a .net port of POI, any number of things could be different ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
        for(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row tmp : hssfSheet){
            for(int i = 0; i<8;i++){
                System.out.println(tmp.getCell(i));
            }               
        }
```

Comment: he is using XSSF to open an XLSX file (2007+).  HSSF will not solve his problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me....

```
int rowNumber;
int previousCell;
int currentCell;
int currentRowNumber;
HSSFCell cell;

while (rows.hasNext()) {
    previousCell = -1;
    currentCell = 0;
    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
        cell = (HSSFCell) cellIterator.next();
        currentCell = cell.getColumnIndex();
        if (previousCell == currentCell-1)  {
            //...
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Blank cell found");
        }
        previousCell = currentCell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List cellDataList = new ArrayList(); 

int lineNumber = 0;   

while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    HSSFRow hssfRow = (HSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
    //System.out.println("Befor If");
    lineNumber++;
    if(lineNumber==1){continue;}
    //System.out.println("Out side if ");

    Iterator<Cell> iterator = hssfRow.cellIterator();
    List<Cell> cellTempList = new ArrayList();
    int current = 0, next = 1;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      Cell hssfCell = iterator.next();
      current = hssfCell.getColumnIndex();

      if(current<next){
          System.out.println("Condition Satisfied");
      }
      else{
          int loop = current-next;
          System.out.println("inside else Loop value : "+(loop));
          for(int k=0;k<loop+1;k++){
             System.out.println("Adding nulls");
             cellTempList.add(null);
             next = next + 1;
          }
      }

      cellTempList.add(hssfCell);

      next = next + 1;
      System.out.println("At End  next value is : "+next);
  }
  cellDataList.add(cellTempList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String[] rowToString(Row row)
{
    Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator() ;
    String[] data = new String[row.getLastCellNum()] ;

    int previousCell = 0 ;

    Cell cell = cells.next() ;
    int currentCell = cell.getColumnIndex();

    while (true)
    {
        if (previousCell == currentCell) {
            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    data[previousCell] = cell.getNumericCellValue()+"" ;
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    data[previousCell] = cell.getStringCellValue() ;
                    break;
                    /* // there could be other cases here.
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                        data[previousCell] =eval.evaluateFormulaCell(cell);
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        data[previousCell] = cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                        data[previousCell] = "";
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                        data[previousCell] = "ERROR";
                        break;
                    */
            }
            if(cells.hasNext()){
                cell = cells.next() ;
                currentCell = cell.getColumnIndex();
            } else {
                break ;
            }

        } else {
            data[previousCell] = "";
        }
        previousCell++ ;

    }

    return data ;

}
```

Comment: please, add comments to your answer

Comment: you should add the comments and explanation in the post not below, also, please look the year of the question

Comment: This method transforms an excel row in an array of strings, without skipping the blank or empty cell values (the corresponding array value will have just an empty string in this case).

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Row row: sheet){
// This will return null if cell is empty / blank
Cell cell = row.getCell(columnNumber);
}
```