# Printing empty Excel cells

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, loops, xls

Here's my code

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

public class ReadExcelFile {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final String fileName = "C:\\temp\\carreras.xls";
        final Vector<Vector<Cell>> dataHolder = ReadCSV(fileName);
        printCellDataToConsole(dataHolder);
    }

    public static Vector<Vector<Cell>> ReadCSV(final String fileName) {
        final Vector<Vector<Cell>> cellVectorHolder = new Vector<Vector<Cell>>();

        try {
            final FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            final POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);
            final HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);
            final HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
            final Iterator<Row> rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
            while (rowIter.hasNext()) {
                final HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
                final Iterator<Cell> cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
                final Vector<Cell> cellStoreVector = new Vector<Cell>();
                while (cellIter.hasNext()) {
                    final HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                    cellStoreVector.addElement(myCell);
                }
                cellVectorHolder.addElement(cellStoreVector);
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return cellVectorHolder;
    }

    private static void printCellDataToConsole(
            final Vector<Vector<Cell>> dataHolder) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataHolder.size(); i++) {
            final Vector<Cell> cellStoreVector = dataHolder.elementAt(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < cellStoreVector.size(); j++) {
                final HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellStoreVector.elementAt(j);
                final String stringCellValue = myCell.toString();
                System.out.print(stringCellValue + "|");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

It works as expected except for one little detail: If it finds an empty cell, it gets skipped. The expected output is:

```
1|2||4
3||7|2
```

however the output is

```
1|2|4
3|7|2
```

How can I iterate through a entire Excel file and get the expected behavior? Correcting the xls files is not an option since we need to parse about 400 excel files.

Comment: You should have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929646/how-to-get-an-excel-blank-cell-value-in-apache-poi

Comment: I searched and didn't find that. Weird. Thank you anyway, the issue is solved.