# Read empty cell using Apache POI Event model

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a huge excel file with tons of columns which looks like this :-

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
abc             def             ghi
        mno             pqr
......
```

The output generated by my code when I print all the values in excel is :-

```
abc;def;ghi;null;null

mno;pqr;null;null;null
```

So, If we look at the output above we can note that the cells where I left blank values were not picked up by the POI library. Is there a way in which I can get these values as null? Or a way to recognize that the values presented skipped blank cells?

Please note: I am not using the usermodel (org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel) but an Event API to process xls and xlsx files.

I am implementing HSSFListener and overriding its processRecord(Record record) method for xls files. For xlsx files I am using javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser and org.xml.sax.XMLReader.

I am using JDK7 with Apache POI 3.7. Can someone please help?

I have already seen this possible duplicate [How to get an Excel Blank Cell Value in Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929646/how-to-get-an-excel-blank-cell-value-in-apache-poi) But this doesn't answer my question as I am using Event API.

Comment: What Event API are you using?

Comment: It's an Event API of Apache POI to address memory footprint issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done, and there are several examples of it which ship with Apache POI. They all relate to Event based xls / xlsx -> CSV, which looks very close to what you're doing. That makes me worry you may be re-inventing the wheel...

For HSSF event model processing, the example you want to look at is [XLS2CSVmra](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hssf/eventusermodel/examples/XLS2CSVmra.java). That is powered by [MissingRecordAwareHSSFListener](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/hssf/eventusermodel/MissingRecordAwareHSSFListener.java)

For XSSF event model, the example you need is [XLSX2CSV](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java)

Comment: I knew that you will reply and save me as always :) Thanks a lot, I will take a look.

Comment: I checked the https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java example however in that example it is adding a comma for any blank value. How can I do it in my example? Below is my code:

Comment: public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name) throws SAXException {
   // Process the last contents as required.
   // Do now, as characters() may be called more than once
   if(nextIsString) {
    try {
     int idx = Integer.parseInt(lastContents);
     lastContents = new XSSFRichTextString(sst.getEntryAt(idx)).toString();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    }
   }
 
   // v => contents of a cell
   // Output after we've seen the string contents
   if(name.equals("v")) {
    values.add(lastContents);
   }
   
   if(name.equals("row")) { ... do something ... }}

Comment: You'd probably be best off asking a new question, as it's impossible to work out from that comment what you're doing and what's wrong...

Comment: Thanks Gagravarr, but I solved it myself by maintaining current column number. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Gagravarr I am having a similar issue, lets say I am using the XLSX2CSV example and its parsing a large excel sheet and i want to output that stream to text file just for specific sheets in workbook, how would I do that ?

Comment: @EduardoDennis Step one would be asking a new question for that, since it really isn't part of this one...

Comment: The xlxs example is not good, you need to know in advance the minimum row number.