# Read empty cell (first column) using Apache POI Event model

Tags: java, apache-poi

This is an enhancement to my old question: [Read empty cell using Apache POI Event model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067558/read-empty-cell-using-apache-poi-event-model).

Actually I am trying to read empty cells and it works when empty cells occur in middle or end columns. However, if first column has empty cells, it doesn't treat it as `BlankRecord.sid` in below code. And due to this the value for that cell is set to empty string. I want to treat the first column too as BlankRecord so that it will be set to `null`.

Here is the code for xls:

```
public void processRecord(Record record) {
        int thisRow = -1;
        String thisStr = null;

        switch (record.getSid()) {
            case BoundSheetRecord.sid:
                boundSheetRecords.add(record);
                break;
            case BOFRecord.sid:
                BOFRecord br = (BOFRecord)record;
                if(br.getType() == BOFRecord.TYPE_WORKSHEET) {
                    // Works by ordering the BSRs by the location of their BOFRecords, and then knowing that we
                    // process BOFRecords in byte offset order
                    if(orderedBSRs == null) {
                        orderedBSRs = BoundSheetRecord.orderByBofPosition(boundSheetRecords);
                    }

                    // Check the existence of sheets
                    if(sheetIndex == 0) {
                        for(int i=0;i<excelSheetList.length;i++) {
                            boolean found = false;
                            for(int j=0;j<orderedBSRs.length;j++) {
                                if(this.getExcelSheetSpecification().equals(MSExcelAdapter.USE_WORKSHEET_NAME)) {
                                    String sheetName = ((BoundSheetRecord) boundSheetRecords.get(j)).getSheetname();
                                    if(excelSheetList[i].equals(sheetName)) {
                                        found = true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    try {
                                        if(Integer.parseInt(excelSheetList[i]) == j) {
                                            found = true;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if(!found)
                                this.warning("processRecord()","Sheet: " + excelSheetList[i] + " does not exist.");
                        }
                    }

                    readCurrentSheet = true;
                    sheetIndex++;
                    if(this.getExcelSheetSpecification().equals(MSExcelAdapter.USE_WORKSHEET_NAME)) {
                        String sheetName = ((BoundSheetRecord) boundSheetRecords.get(sheetIndex-1)).getSheetname();
                        if(!canRead(sheetName)) {
                            readCurrentSheet = false;                       
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(!canRead(sheetIndex + "")) {
                            readCurrentSheet = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            case SSTRecord.sid:
                sstRecord = (SSTRecord) record;
                break;

            case BlankRecord.sid:
                BlankRecord brec = (BlankRecord) record;

                thisRow = brec.getRow();
                thisStr = null;
                values.add(thisStr);
                columnCount++;
                break;

            case FormulaRecord.sid:
                FormulaRecord frec = (FormulaRecord) record;

                thisRow = frec.getRow();
                if(Double.isNaN( frec.getValue() )) {
                    // Formula result is a string
                    // This is stored in the next record
                    outputNextStringRecord = true;
                    nextRow = frec.getRow();
                } else {
                    thisStr = formatListener.formatNumberDateCell(frec);
                }
                break;  

            case StringRecord.sid:
                if(outputNextStringRecord) {
                    // String for formula
                    StringRecord srec = (StringRecord)record;
                    thisStr = srec.getString();
                    thisRow = nextRow;
                    outputNextStringRecord = false;
                }
                break;

            case LabelSSTRecord.sid:
                if(readCurrentSheet) {
                    LabelSSTRecord lsrec = (LabelSSTRecord) record;
                    thisRow = lsrec.getRow() + 1;
                    if(rowNumberList.contains(thisRow + "") ||
                            (rowNumberList.contains(END_OF_ROWS) && thisRow >= secondLastRow)) {
                        if(sstRecord == null) {
                            thisStr = "(No SST Record, can't identify string)";
                        } else {
                            thisStr = sstRecord.getString(lsrec.getSSTIndex()).toString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            case NumberRecord.sid:
                if(readCurrentSheet) {
                    NumberRecord numrec = (NumberRecord) record;
                    thisRow = numrec.getRow() + 1;
                    if(rowNumberList.contains(thisRow + "") ||
                                (rowNumberList.contains(END_OF_ROWS) && thisRow >= secondLastRow)) {
                            thisStr = formatListener.formatNumberDateCell(numrec); // Format
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        // Handle missing column
        if(record instanceof MissingCellDummyRecord) {
            thisStr = "";
        }

        // If we got something to print out, do so
        if(thisStr != null) {
            values.add(thisStr);
            columnCount++;
        }

        // Handle end of row
        if(record instanceof LastCellOfRowDummyRecord) { 
               .....
        }
        ...
```

With xlsx if the first column has empty cell it is being skipped. Here is the code for xlsx:

```
 /** 
     * Default handler for parsing an excel sheet
     * @see org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler
     */
    private class SheetHandler extends DefaultHandler {
        private SharedStringsTable sst;
        private String lastContents;
        private boolean nextIsString;
        private MSExcelReader reader;

        private int thisColumn = -1;
        private int lastColumnNumber = -1;  // The last column printed to the output stream

        private SheetHandler(SharedStringsTable sst, MSExcelReader reader) {
            this.sst = sst;
            this.reader = reader;
        }

        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            // c => cell
            if(name.equals("c")) {
                // Figure out if the value is an index in the SST
                String cellType = attributes.getValue("t");
                if(cellType != null && cellType.equals("s")) {
                    nextIsString = true;
                } else {
                    nextIsString = false;
                }
                // Get the cell reference
                String r = attributes.getValue("r");
                int firstDigit = -1;
                for (int c = 0; c < r.length(); ++c) {
                    if (Character.isDigit(r.charAt(c))) {
                        firstDigit = c;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                thisColumn = nameToColumn(r.substring(0, firstDigit));
            }
            // Clear contents cache
            lastContents = "";
        }

        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name) throws SAXException {
            // Process the last contents as required.
            // Do now, as characters() may be called more than once
            if(nextIsString) {
                try {
                    int idx = Integer.parseInt(lastContents);
                    lastContents = new XSSFRichTextString(sst.getEntryAt(idx)).toString();
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                }
            }

            // v => contents of a cell
            // Output after we've seen the string contents
            if(name.equals("v")) {
                for (int i = lastColumnNumber; i < thisColumn - 1; ++i)
                    values.add(null);  // Add empty string for missing columns

                values.add(lastContents);

                // Update column
                if (thisColumn > -1)
                    lastColumnNumber = thisColumn;
            }

            if(name.equals("row")) {
            ...
```

Same as my old question things to mention: I am not using the usermodel (org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel) but an Event API to process xls and xlsx files.

I am implementing HSSFListener and overriding its processRecord(Record record) method for xls files. For xlsx files I am using javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser and org.xml.sax.XMLReader.

I am using JDK7 with Apache POI 3.7. Can someone please help?

I have excel file with following columns which looks like this :-

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7
        Parag   Joshi   Pune                100     
        Parag   Joshi   Pune    200
```

The output generated by my code when I print all the values in excel is :-

```
;Parag;Joshi;Pune;null;100;null
;Parag;Joshi;Pune;200;null;null
```

See above that it printed empty string for first column but for other columnd it printed the value null. I want first column to print the same value null.

Comment: For the XLS (HSSF) case, can you clarify what isn't working for you with MissingCellAwareRecord support?

Comment: @Gagravarr: Thanks. Please see what is not working above. I have edited the question in the end.

Comment: @Gagravarr: Can you please help?

Comment: Take a look at [XLS2CSVmra](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hssf/eventusermodel/examples/XLS2CSVmra.java) which is a POI example. That correctly manages to use the EventModel to print out a CSV, including missing cells. Compare your code to that, and use that to work out what you have done wrong!

Comment: @Gagravarr it doesn't handle empty cells properly, it needs the minimum number of columns to work, which isn't a good way.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau The file format is a sparse one, so the user needs to say how many columns they care about, as that info isn't stored helpfully in the file at run time

Comment: @Gagravarr And it's a shame it isn't there. You either have to know in advance or read the whole thing to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a cleaner way than this, please advice, thanks!

Create an ArrayList to store columnIndex;

```
    ArrayList<Integer> listAllColInRow = new ArrayList<>();
```

Create an ArrayList to store your data;

```
    addDataToRow = new ArrayList<>();
```

Add each columnIndex to listAllColInRow;

```
    while (cells.hasNext()) {   
        cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();    
        int col = cell.getColumnIndex();    
        listAllColInRow.add(col);    
    }
```

Get the first Column index in each row so we can check if it is the the first column;

```
    Integer a = listAllColInRow.get(0);
```

If its not the first column, add null to the  first index of your arrayList which is addDataToRow in this example and so on until it reach the first column;

```
    // while a is not the 1st column    
    while( a != 0){    
        //add null to the 1st index of the ArrayList    
        addDataToRow.add(0,null);    
        a--;    
    }
```

Comment: It is always a good idea to add some explanation to your code