# Getting exception while trying to export and color rows in excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

So I want to color rows when exporting to Excel but I'm getting a *NullPointerException*.

This is my code:

```
HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = hssfWorkbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex())

for (int i = 3; i < hssfSheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < hssfSheet.getRow(i).getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); j++) {
        hssfSheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    }              
}
```

So I noticed when I put a really small numbers of rows (like 3 or 4) it works fine, as soon as I put more, it giving me the exception. I have at least 200 rows, it depends on a filter that the user selects. How to fix this?

Comment: Some cells between 0 and getPhysicalNumberOfCells could be empty

Comment: @ScaryWombat okay, then how to color that row if it has empty cells?

Comment: A quick search finds https://stackoverflow.com/a/6680841/2310289

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes, that solve my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because `HSSFSheet#getRow(int)` and `Row#getCell(int)` return `null` when the row/cell is *undefined*. Therefore, the a consecutive calls `.getCell(...)` or `.setCellStyle(...)` throw a NPE. You can insert a `NULL`-check to only loop over the cells if the row is defined.

Additionally, you should use `getLastCellNum()` instead of `getPhysicalNumberOfCells()` to loop over the cells. Don't forget to use `<=` as both sides are zero-based.

If you want to color empty cells as well, you can use [`Row#getCell(int, Row.MissingCellPolicy)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell-int-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.MissingCellPolicy-) to create the cells on the fly:

```java
for (int i = 3; i <= hssfSheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
    HSSFRow row = hssfSheet.getRow(i);
    if (row != null) {
        for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
            HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
        }
    }
}
```

If empty cells should not be colored, you can use the following snippet:

```java
for (int i = 3; i <= hssfSheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
    HSSFRow row = hssfSheet.getRow(i);
    if (row != null) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
        }
    }
}
```